# Command result at the top of terminal

Tags: terminal, top

Is there a way to display the command result at the top of the terminal and the prompt below it? So that I could see the result, e.g.

```
while true;
do
    sensors | grep temp1;
    sleep 2;
done
```

and still use the terminal?

Something like this:

```
temp1:        +36.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp1:        +41.4°C  (high = +70.0°C)
user@magi:~$ echo 'hello'
user@magi:~$ hello
user@magi:~$ echo 'hello2'
```

I would like to get this effect on Raspberry PI / Raspbian CLI.
Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but you can use screen, tmux, dvtm or something similar to split screen horizontally and display your command in the upper part.

Comment: I do not think that is doable without some utility - as already suggested. But a quick google turned up something promising using screen: https://tomlee.co/2011/10/gnu-screen-splitting/

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1398132/432690).